# Delphi MSBuild.exe error MSB4057 but can use IDE build project

Tags: delphi, msbuild

I use Delphi XE4 on Windows7 and use Microsoft.NET/Framework/V3.5/MSBuild.exe .

I have added the MSBuild path to the environment variable.

But got this error :(

```
$MSBuild.exe Project3.dproj /target:Build /property:configutation=Debug
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 3.5.30729.5420
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.8762]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 2017/10/30 ▒W▒▒ 10:45:40.
Project "C:\DXE4_LangDLL\Project3.dproj" on node 0 (Build target(s)).
C:\DXE4_LangDLL\Project3.dproj : error MSB4057: The target "Build" does not exist in the project.
Done Building Project "C:\DXE4_LangDLL\Project3.dproj" (Build target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\DXE4_LangDLL\Project3.dproj" (Build target) (1) ->
  C:\DXE4_LangDLL\Project3.dproj : error MSB4057: The target "Build" does not exist in the project.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.00
```

I tried use Microsoft.NET/Framework/V2.0.50727/MSBuild.exe and got the same message.

I was confuse because used Delphi IDE to build project successfully.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you using the RAD Studio command prompt? It sets some other environmental variables that are needed.

Comment: @KenWhite I use Git bash to run command line. Dose the reason cause my failure?

Comment: @KenWhite I use RAD Studio command prompt to run my command line and Build sueeded! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set first the environmental variables. There is a batch file, at the path

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\XX\rsvars.bat

that i use for command-line batch files, where XX the version of your RAD Studio.

I am not sure if it will work for Git bash as it is, but you can create a batch file that will combine the lines of `rsvars.bat` and the `MSBuild` line, and execute it

Something like:

```
@SET BDS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\XX
@SET BDSINCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\XX\include
@SET BDSCOMMONDIR=C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\XX
@SET FrameworkDir=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
@SET FrameworkVersion=v3.5
@SET FrameworkSDKDir=
@SET PATH=%FrameworkDir%;%FrameworkSDKDir%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\XX\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\XX\bin64;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\InterBase\redist\InterBaseXE3\IDE_spoof;%PATH%
@SET LANGDIR=EN
@SET PLATFORM=
@SET PlatformSDK=

$MSBuild.exe Project3.dproj /target:Build /property:configutation=Debug
```